# Tap not working towards right edge of iPhone XS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a vertical toolbar shifted to right edge in screen because of interference by 3D Touch on left. It was working fine until now but when tested in new iPhoneXS, tap is not working properly. Tap works only towards left end of buttons and does not work towards right edge in screen. However, if we long press on right edge, it works fine. I also noticed that UITouchPhase.Moved is fired after UITouchPhase.Began, even though x and y coordinate do not change. Any ideas, how to fix this issue?

In toolbar's buttons, there are two grids i.e one color indicator (tap works fine) and other to select drawing tool (tap does not work, long press does). Tried adjusting rows and columns in grid, but that did not help.

Comment: Does it work on other device except iPhoneXS?

Comment: Yes, it does. It even works in 3D touch devices like 6s and 6s plus. Any idea, why its behaving this way in XS?

Comment: No idea about it. Through your description, it should be a specific device problem? Did you test it on a real device? Or try to test it on another XS?

Comment: Yes, I tested it in couple of actual XS devices and problem replicates in each of it.

Comment: No idea about why it only happens on XS.